# Glimpse in SOA Architecture

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I want to know whether glimpse works in SOA Architecture or not. I am using SOA Architecture in which My client is MVC Application. The client makes call to the WCF Service which is hosted through Window Service. For testing purpose I am running my application and service both at local debugging mode.
I have already Installed glimpse in my Client MVC Application.
Is there any way how I can get know how much amount of time the service is taking to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported in that sense that everything is assumed to be running inside the same application. There is already an [open issue (Glimpse v2 - Suppport chained service calls)](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/337) that mentions this shortcoming and it is definitely something we would like to support in the future.